# How to set <a> tag's text is on center of image?

Tags: html, css

I want to use button that background image is mine and text is on center of image which is button's background. I used this:

```
  <li>  
    <a href="@Url.Action( "Start", "Home" )">
       <img alt = "" src="@Url.Content( "~/Content/images/buttonimage.png" )" height=23px; width=70px; />Start
    </a>
</li>
```

But, "Start" text is not on image, it seems after image. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following code to achieve what you want.

**HTML:**

```
<li>  
    <a href="@Url.Action( "Start", "Home" )" class="btnImg">
        Start
    </a>
</li>
```

**CSS:**

```
.btnImg{
     background: url(/url/of/image.png);
     width: 70px;
     height: 23px;
     text-align:center;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why not use the button input tag ?

`<input id="myButton" type="button" value="Start" onclick="location.href='~/Content/images/buttonimage.png'" />`

in the css

```
input[type="button"]:active, input[type="submit"]:active
{
     background: url(/url/of/image.png);
     width: 70px;
     height: 23px;
}
```

Comment: that does not sound right, are you clearing the value with some java script? Have you made sure your font colour is different to the image colour?

Answer (score 1):

One method using CSS background images.

Unline examples above this also does **vertical centering**.

IE7+ compatible method:

```
/* http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/ CSS Table Method explained */
.imagePortlet .image-wrapper {
    display: table;
}

/* Text-over-image using relative + absolute positioning trick */
.imagePortlet .text {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Related HTML code. The image is dynamically inserted on the server-side, but if it's a static image you can simply put width and height to `.image-wrapper` class:

```
    <a title="" href="http://localhost" class="outer-wrapper">
        <div style="background: url(http://localhost/yourimage.png) no-repeat top left; width: 232px; height: 93px" class="image-wrapper">
            <div class="text">Text on the image here</div>
        </div>
    </a>
```

Note that inline style must be generated based on the actual image dimensions. I do this by reading the image properties on the server-side. You may avoid knowing the exact image dimensions when using modern browsers, but then you lose IE compatibility.